# Can't return QuerySet filter to html page

Tags: python, django

i want filter employee form department and site by user filter and submit

**i post value form html to definition in views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def empFil(request):
    dep = request.POST.get('dep',None)
    site = request.POST.get('site',None)
    print(dep)
    print(site)

    fil = TB_employee.objects.filter(dep_id = dep, site_id = site).select_related('site_id','dep_id','pos_id','sec_id')
    print(fil)


    return render(request,'app/employee.html',{'fil':fil})
```

**this command line**

```
21
2
<QuerySet [<TB_employee: TB_employee object (4892)>, <TB_employee: TB_employee object (4916)>]>
```

**in employee.html**

```
{% for e in fil %}  
     <tr>
         <td>{{e.en}}</td>
         <td>{{e.name_th}}</td>
         <td>{{e.surname_th}}</td>
         <td>{{e.name_eng}}</td>
         <td>{{e.surname_eng}}</td>
         <td>{{e.pos_id.pos_name}}</td>
         <td>{{e.dep_id.dep_name}}</td>
         <td>{{e.site_id.site_name}}</td>
         <td>{{e.hire_date}}</td>
         <td>{{e.sec_id.sec_name}}</td>
         <td>{{e.emp_type}}</td>
         <td>{{e.emp_status}}</td>
         <td>{{e.emp_email}}</td>
         <td>{{e.budget}}</td>
 </tr>


{% endfor %}
```

> in html page cannot show data

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem employee.html in table not show data

Comment: Did you check your DOM to see is there any element which rendered by that data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add space between curly braces. So for example, `{{e.en}}` should be `{{ e.en }}`